# function autoload class error on LAMP server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I developed my php software on EasyPHP 3.5.9 and all was perfect, now I installed LAMP on ubuntu 12.04 x64. 
If I try to upload my software on ubuntu I display a white page.
I looked on apache logs and I've found this error

**"PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'unable to load Session' in /var/www/xxxx/index.php:7\nstack trace:\n#0 /var/www/xxxx/index.php(11): __autoload('session')\n#1 {main}"**

```
<?PHP
function __autoload($class_name) {
if(file_exists('class/class.' . $class_name . '.php')) {
    require_once('class/class.' . $class_name . '.php'); 

} else {
    throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.");
}
}
$ses = new Session();
```

Wuy it does not load the class? The LAMP's configuration seems to be correct.
What could I have forgotten? How can I resolve?
Thanks

Comment: I need to see your class.

Comment: is your class file names "class.Session.php" or "class.session.php"? In some systems those can be two different files.

Comment: if I set `require_once('class/class.session.php');` go well. I do not understand why it is not loaded with autoload.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to debug it:

1. Try printing the class name to see if the correct class name is passed on to the function or not

   function __autoload($class_name) { **echo $class_name;**
   if(file_exists('class/class.' . $class_name . '.php')) {
2. As commented by Ares, see that you are not trying to open class.Session.php while the real name is class.session.php as this is different on some system.
3. Try using trim function to remove any space before or after the class name.

   function __autoload($class_name) { **echo $class_name;** trim($class_name);
   if(file_exists('class/class.' . $class_name . '.php')) {